# What is Sanz's tablature for the baroque guitar?

Tags: guitar, notation, tablature, baroque-period

[Gaspar Sanz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaspar_Sanz) had a tablature system for the baroque guitar which features a mapping between alphabetical letters and chords. From the linked page:

> Sanz's tablature is remarkable in that it is topologically correct,
>   representing the first string in the lower line and the fifth string
>   in the highest printed line. In this epoch, guitars only had five
>   strings. It also features the "italian alphabet", a shorthand system
>   that assigns a chord to each letter, so that melodic chord
>   progressions can be written and read very neatly (with rhythm
>   information) as a simple sequence of letters, a concept related to the
>   recent Nashville system. For example, there is a "Zarabanda francesa"
>   (french sarabande) which includes the sequence
>   CIFI+H<sup>2</sup>+G<sup>2</sup>K<sup>2</sup>IFCM<sup>2</sup>N<sup>2</sup>CAIC, which means:
>
> - CIFI: D major chord, A major, E major, A major
> - +H<sup>2</sup>+G<sup>2</sup>K<sup>2</sup>: E minor, B major, E minor, F# major, B minor
> - IFCM<sup>2</sup>N<sup>2</sup>: A major, E major, A major, E major (variation), A major (variation)
> - CAIC: D major, G major, A major, D major

There are 2 things which confuse me in the above:

1. How is this system topological? I don't see a schematic representation of the strings. It looks like the paragraph is mixing Sanz's tablature and an "italian alphabet" system.
2. How is the alphabetical notation mapped to chords? e.g., `C` seems to be mostly D major but once it's A major. Also, where is the rhythmic information?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, this paragraph is about Sanz' *influence* on both tablature and symbolic chord notation. It does not imply that both things are necessarily combined. In fact the [example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Instrucci%C3%B2n_de_M%C3%B9sica_sobre_la_Guitarra_Espa%C3%B1ola_-_Passacalles.jpg/220px-Instrucci%C3%B2n_de_M%C3%B9sica_sobre_la_Guitarra_Espa%C3%B1ola_-_Passacalles.jpg) shown on the same page does not show chord notation at all, but it does feature a representation of strings as described.
2. There is no clear relationship between italian alphabet notation and musical pitch notation, and the choice of chord symbols appears to be arbitrary (see [this article](http://www.guitarramagazine.com/History.do?typeName=history&recordId=3)). -- The Wikipedia example shows rhythm indicated by small notes above the tablature staff.

Answer (score 2):

1. Sanz' tablature is topological in the sense that it reflects the order of the strings as viewed by the player:

> [image] [image]
>
> - [*Instrucción de Música*](http://imslp.org/wiki/Instrucci%C3%B3n_de_M%C3%BAsica_(Sanz,_Gaspar)) (p18)

as opposed to a mirror image of them, as other tablatures of the time (and previously) used:

> [image]

or notes without indication of string:

> [image] [image]

2. Here is Sanz' own illustration of the Italian alphabet:

> [image]
>
> - [*Instrucción de Música*](http://imslp.org/wiki/Instrucci%C3%B3n_de_M%C3%BAsica_(Sanz,_Gaspar)) (p11)

As you can see, rhythmic information is indicated by a combination of super-script notes and downwards/upwards 'ticks' (indicating strum direction):

> [image]
>
> - p20
>
> [image]
>
> - p14

**Note:** that's an error on the wiki page. **C** indeed refers to a D chord, not an A.

Answer (score 1):

The Wiki article has a [link](http://bdh.bne.es/bnesearch/CompleteSearch.do?field=todos&text=gaspar%20sanz&showYearItems=&exact=on&textH=&advanced=false&completeText=&pageSize=1&pageSizeAbrv=10&pageNumber=1) to the Biblioteca scan of his work.   Book 1 is mostly strummed using the alphabet notation.  Page 27 & 29 has a table matching the letters to tablature.

[www.donaldsauter.com/gaspar-sanz.htm](http://www.donaldsauter.com/gaspar-sanz.htm) discusses his tablature, and renders Book 2 in modern tablature.

On the tablature, rhythm is indicted by notes above the score.  They are also on the strumming pages, but more compactly.